# Another IComparer question - multiple comparison properties

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

Apologies if similar issues exist. It's just that no useful exception is thrown when List.Sort() is called, just the app-ending:

```
Unable to sort because the IComparer.Compare method returns inconsistent
results. Either a value does not compare equal to itself, or one value     repeatedly
compared to another value yields different results.
```

I'm trying to sort a List of UserModels, say:

```
class UserModel
{
  public string GivenName;
  public string Surname;
}
```

The sort should go by Surname and then GivenName, like in LINQ's `.OrderBy(u => u.Surname).ThenBy(u => u.GivenName)`. I want to use a comparer though because I need to BinarySearch() it later.

Comparer is:

```
class CustomComparer : IComparer<UserModel>
{
  public int Compare(UserModel l, UserModel r)
            { 
                if (l == null && r == null) return 0;
                if (l == null) return -1;
                if (r == null) return 1;
                if (l.Surname == null) return -1;
                if (r.Surname == null) return 1;

                int compareSurname = string.Compare(l.Surname, r.Surname);
                if (compareSurname != 0)
                    return compareSurname;

                if (l.GivenName == null) return -1;
                if (r.GivenName == null) return 1;
                return string.Compare(l.GivenName, r.GivenName);
            }
}
```

Can anyone see an issue with this? I can't see an obvious situation where the same object could return unequal, or swapped l/r params return anything other than -1/1 swapped. But there must be :(

Comment: Have you written unit tests around this? Should be pretty straightforward to test.

Comment: Agreed - although I might not have considered the edge case pointed out as per the answer below!

Comment: You check for surnames (not) being `null`, implying that user models can have a missing surname. But what if the surname is an empty string? Does the surname being an empty string mean a different thing for your user models than the surname being `null`? Note that `null` and an empty string do not compare as equal using `string.Compare`. Is treating `null` and an empty string differently being part of the desired sorting behavior?

Comment: Yes string.Compare's default for handling null & empty good enough in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an issue if both `Surname` or `GivenName` are `null`
Here you did right

```
if (l == null && r == null) return 0;
if (l == null) return -1;
if (r == null) return 1;
```

But not here for instance

```
if (l.Surname == null) return -1;
if (r.Surname == null) return 1;
```

In fact, you could simply do that I think

```
public int Compare(UserModel l, UserModel r)
{ 
    if (l == null && r == null) return 0;
    if (l == null) return -1;
    if (r == null) return 1;

    int compareSurname = string.Compare(l.Surname, r.Surname);
    if (compareSurname != 0)
        return compareSurname;

    return string.Compare(l.GivenName, r.GivenName);
}
```

Comment: Sir, I doff my hat.

Comment: Indeed, the standard method for building a comparison list is `int compare = someType.Compare(a.value1, b.value1); if (compare != 0) return compare; compare = someType.Compare(a.value2, b.value2); if (compare != 0) return compare;` etc until the final line `return compare;`